# call alertifyjs from typescripts

Tags: typescript, alertifyjs

I'm trying to migrate some js code to typescript.
Specifically I'm having trouble with AlertifyJs. Now Alertify seems to be many things.

1. a [discontinued project](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/) by fabien-d
2. picked up and continued  alertifyjs dot org
3. picked up by MohammadYounes alertifyjs dot com

Now I can find the d.ts for (1) on DefinitelyTyped, but none for the others.
I want to use (3)!

I would like to somehow wrap or call directly **alertify.confirm("you go", "girl");** from ts.

*How can I achieve this?*

Thanks

PS: Coding in vs2015

EDIT:
Thought I'd provide you beutiful nerds with a code snippet of what I got somefar

```ts
///<reference path="../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts"/>
///<reference path="../typings/toastr/toastr.d.ts"/>

module mymodule.Web {
export class CommonTools {

    constructor() {
        toastr.options.closeButton = false;
    }

    showInfo(title: string, message: string) {
        toastr.info(message, title);
    }
    showConfirm(title: string, message: string) {
     //**code goes here**
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest (and least safe or elegant) solution could be to add this somewhere in the global scope in your typescript.

```
declare var alertify: any;
```

Like this, typescript will know about the `alertify` variable.

If you are more precise, you can introduce your own (for example) `AlertifyJSStatic` interface with those methods you want to use, and give that as type of `alertify` variable.

```
interface AlertifyJSStatic {
  confirm(a: string, b:string);
}

declare var alertify: AlertifyJSStatic;
```

Sometimes it's easier to add your own needs quickly than get lost in `d.ts` libraries (and versions).

Comment: That worked beautifully, thank you so much.
Clear, concise and simple answer. I wanna buy a beer now!

Answer (score 0):

*I see there is an accepted answer, but this was my solution.

For my angular project, after installing with npm, in your import section of your TS file, copy the following...

```
import * as alertifyJs from 'alertifyjs';
```

From there, the usage is just as you desired.

```
alertifyJs.confirm('alertify is working');
```

hope this helps. cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you have a global installation of the library, declare it like this

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    alertify: {
      success: Function;
      [key: string]: Function; // for all others
    };
  }
}
```

Now safely use

```
window.alertify.success(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Zoltán Tamási](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1323504/zolt%c3%a1n-tam%c3%a1si)'s answer I created an interface which helped me solve my compilation errors in TypeScript:

```
// globals/alertify.type.js

interface AlertifyJsStatic {
    alert (title: any, message: any, onok?: string);
    confirm (title: any, message: any, onok?: any, oncancel?: any);
    prompt (title: any, message: any, value?: string, onok?: any, oncancel?: any);
    notify (message: string, type?: string, wait?: number, callback?: any);
}

declare var alertify: AlertifyJsStatic;
```

And I reference it wherever used via [Triple-Slash directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html)

```
/// <reference path="globals/alertify.type.ts" />
```